# From UBI8 to Alpine in a Docker File getting some errors

Tags: dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to change a *Dockerfile* execution from `UBI8` to `alpine:latest` version (being the version 8), I have done some changes to the *Dockerfile*, but, now, I am not able to identify the cause of the errors, because I am not getting enough logs to see what is happening, basically I changed,

```bash
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
```

to:

```bash
FROM docker-all.repo.company.com/alpine:latest
RUN apk update \
  && apk add --no-cache bash \
  && apk add --no-cache curl \
  && apk add --no-cache openjdk8-jre
```

In this section:

```bash
RUN cd ${TEMP} --progress=plain \
&& curl -L https://download.sonatype.com/clm/server/nexus-iq-server-${SERVER_VERSION}-bundle.tar.gz --output nexus-iq-server-${SERVER_VERSION}-bundle.tar.gz \
&& echo "${SERVER_SHA256} nexus-iq-server-${SERVER_VERSION}-bundle.tar.gz" > nexus-iq-server-${SERVER_VERSION}-bundle.tar.gz.sha256 \
&& sha256sum -c nexus-iq-server-${SERVER_VERSION}-bundle.tar.gz.sha256 \
&& tar -xvf nexus-iq-server-${SERVER_VERSION}-bundle.tar.gz \
&& mv nexus-iq-server-${SERVER_VERSION}.jar ${HOME} \
&& cd ${HOME} \
&& rm -rf ${TEMP} \
```

I am getting the error:

> ERROR: failed to solve: process
> did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

The error is coming from the `sha256sum` check command.

Not sure if Docker `RUN` need to add something else when moving to Alpine and because the container is not created I am not able to see the logs.

Any clues?

Comment: First step you should do is to identify exactly the line that fails in those 8 lines of code.

Comment: It seems like is in the sha256sum line

Answer (score 0):

Your issue most likely comes from your checksum that is missing a space.

A correct sha256 checksum would look like

```
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  file.tar.gz
```

```
## this is the sha256 // mind the **two** spaces here ----------^^ filename
```

The first space is just a space to differentiate the checksum from the filename, but the second space is a flag to indicate binary or text input mode.

And because your line creating the checksum to validate is missing this second space, the check does fail.

This difference might well be coming from the fact that the `sha256sum` command of Alpine is the BusyBox one, which does not support the BSD style of checksum while the GNU implementation of `sha256sum` does:

> Three input formats are supported. Either the default output format described above, the `--tag` output format, **or the BSD reversed mode format which is similar to the default mode, but doesn’t use a character to distinguish binary and text modes**.

<sup>*Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/md5sum-invocation.html, emphasis, mine*</sup>

So, your fix should be as simple as ensuring you have **two spaces** in the line

```bash
&& echo "${SERVER_SHA256}  nexus-iq-server-${SERVER_VERSION}-bundle.tar.gz" > nexus-iq-server-${SERVER_VERSION}-bundle.tar.gz.sha256 \
```